# Swift: addSublayer in specific cell in Tableview not every cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, addsubview

I have a single tableView that is displaying the data for save data from CoreData. The table is for a single day and the cells are sorted by the readings taken at that time. I have many readings per save so I have a single cell that shows all the data as sub labels in views that looks like another table in the cell ( didn't go for putting the table in a cell approach). 
All is well but I have a pain diagram that displays where you save the location. I get it to show the point in the right place on the diagram BUT when this appears it then adds the point to every cell with that diagram for all the times on that day.
How can I specify a specific cell for the sublayer to be added to?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let OurData = people[indexPath.row] as! UserData

    let cell: CalenderDataTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dataCalenderCell") as! CalenderDataTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = GlobalColourConstants.tableViewBackground


// MARK: diagram cell

// LocationX and LocationY represent the decimal ration of how far from the origin the point is e.g. (locationX: 0.5, locationY: 0.5) = centrePoint 

  if let locationX: Float = OurData.painDiagramLocationX {
    print("locationx \(locationX)")

    if locationX == 0 {
      cell.painLocationBackgroundView.layer.borderColor = GlobalColourConstants.noteColourArray[0].CGColor
      cell.painLocationBackgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

// This cell.painLocationImageView = nil is suppose to remove image from cells that don't have a pain diagram. However it crashes the table.

//          cell.painLocationImageView = nil 
    } else {

      let imageName = "Torso Female"
      let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
      cell.painLocationImageView.image = image

      if let locationY: Float = OurData.painDiagramLocationY {
        cell.painLocationBackgroundView.layer.borderColor = GlobalColourConstants.painColourArray[0].CGColor
        cell.painLocationBackgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = GlobalColourConstants.painColourArray[0].CGColor

        print("locationy \(locationY)")

        let pictureOriginX = (cell.painLocationImageView.bounds.origin.x)
        let pictureOriginY = (cell.painLocationImageView.bounds.origin.y)

        let pointOriginX = cell.painLocationImageView.bounds.width * CGFloat(locationX)
        let pointOriginY = cell.painLocationImageView.bounds.height * CGFloat(locationY)

        let circleRadius = CGFloat(8)

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: pointOriginX,y: pointOriginY), radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

        //change the fill color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        //you can change the stroke color
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        //you can change the line width
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

        cell.painLocationImageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just a short overview, So you get your answer**

UITableView is highly optimized, and thus only keep On-screen visible rows in memory. Now, All rows Cells are cached in Pool and are reused and not regenerated. Whenever, user scrolls the UITableView, it adds the just-hidden rows in Pool and reuses them for next to be visible rows. *So you add the sublayer in one cell, and once cell gets reused, you see the same sublayer in other cell.*

**So, now, coming to your answer**

in your method cellForRowAtIndexPath --

Always reset the values for each index :

For ex. **if condition is true add sublayer, if not then remove sublayer**

***A WORD OF SUGGESTION***

Since you are dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, which is very best optimized, but since you are adding a sublayer programmatically, after view is being dequeued, there is a very much chance that you might be adding the sublayers on the view, which already have sublayer added.

You should get reference to your sublayer, and check if it is not already added.

Comment: Thank you I could also have a dot image that is hidden or visible maybe. I will try your suggestion later today.

Comment: I have used  cell.painLocationImageView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll() and that removes the unwanted ones. However how can i reference sublayers I tried    if (shapeLayer != nil) { cell.painLocationImageView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll() } and that doesn't work